# Dealing with Error in Analyized code during CodeFix using Roslyn

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

When writing an Analyzer how do I deal with a line with multiple errors that would effect my CodeFix. For example I want the type of an Expression but the Expression has undeclared functions so its Type is an Error expressed as a "?".

If I return the original document or Nothing Visual Studio still offers the CodeFix but there is no Diff Shown and the Error from the Code Analyzer is shown.

Is there some way for the CodeFix not to be offered if there are multiple errors such that the CodeFix won't work?

[image: Line with 2 Errors]

Answer (score 0):

What I found is it seems that this needs to be handled in the FixProvider. I have the start of the common code needed. It seems you need to look at errors in the entire expression not just the Context of the issue. Using the context you can find the whole expression, or line or block you want to look for errors in. The compare each error in the block with the ones you want to handle. If you find one that will effect your fix you can exit before you register the fix provider. I am open to learning an easier way but the code below does work. It could be shortened but for clarity and debugging it is easier when I keep lines simple.

```
    Public NotOverridable Overrides ReadOnly Property FixableDiagnosticIds As ImmutableArray(Of String) = ImmutableArray.Create(DiagnosticId.ERR_StrictDisallowsImplicitProc.ToDiagnosticId, DiagnosticId.ERR_StrictDisallowImplicitObject.ToDiagnosticId, DiagnosticId.ERR_NameNotDeclared1.ToDiagnosticId)

    Public NotOverridable Overrides Async Function RegisterCodeFixesAsync(context As CodeFixContext) As Task
        Dim root As SyntaxNode = Await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Dim Model As SemanticModel = Await context.Document.GetSemanticModelAsync(context.CancellationToken)
        Dim firstDiagnostic As Diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First()
        Dim diagnosticSpanStart As Integer = firstDiagnostic.Location.SourceSpan.Start
        Dim declarationSyntax As SyntaxNode = root.FindToken(diagnosticSpanStart).Parent.FirstAncestorOrSelfOfType(GetType(VariableDeclaratorSyntax))
        If declarationSyntax IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each DiagnosticEntry As Diagnostic In Model.GetDiagnostics(declarationSyntax.Span)
                ' Does Diagnostic contain any of the errors I care about?
                If FixableDiagnosticIds.Any(Function(m) m.ToString = DiagnosticEntry.Id.ToString) Then
                    Continue For
                End If
                Exit Function
            Next
```